# Creating a vibrator for Android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add vibration effects to my Android game. I found some code that seems to work, but it's deprecated. What's the current way to create and deploy a vibrator?

```
var vibrator:Vibrator = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
               vibrator.vibrate(createPredefined(EFFECT_CLICK))
            }else{
                vibrator.vibrate(50)
            }
```

The parts that are showing up as deprecated are "VIBRATOR-SERVICE" and vibrate.vibrate(50).

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 : Add permission to the `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Step 2 : You can use this function for vibration.

```java
if (ctx != null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
        val vibratorManager =
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
        val vibrator = vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK))
    } else {
        val v = ctx.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK))
        } else {
            v.vibrate(200L)
        }
    }
}
```